# How to make the InlineKeyboardButton in Telegram trigger a command?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to use an `InlineKeyboardButton` in my python telegram bot to trigger the `next` command. I tried to draw inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62431860/13278912), but I must be missing something. Indeed, when I click on the "next" button in the conversation, I get the following error message: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'`. The expected "Going forward, that's good!" message doesn't show up in the conversation.

How could I fix my code to correctly launch the command by clicking on the button, while not losing the ability to also call the command with `/next` in the chat?

```
def start(update, context):
    context.user_data["step"] = 0  # Initialize step counter
    update.message.reply_text(
        f"Hello, you're starting at step {context.user_data['step']}.",
        reply_markup=menu_keyboard(),
    )


def next(update, context):
    context.user_data["step"] += 1
    update.message.reply_text("Going forward!")
    update.message.reply_text(
        f"We're now at step {context.user_data['step']}.", reply_markup=menu_keyboard()
    )


def menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("➡️ Next", callback_data="next")]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    if query.data == "next":
        next(update, context)


def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("next", next))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply\_text'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564632/how-to-solve-this-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-re)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That could indeed be a workaround, but as I understand, I would then lose the ability to launch the command textually (with `/next` in the chat). Ideally, I would like to allow the user to launch this command both by clicking on the button or by calling it textually.

Comment: My intention was not so suggest a workaround :D The point is that the `update` passed to `button` has `update.callback_query`, but not `update.message`. OTOH, `next` expects the `update` argument to have `update.message`, but not `update.callback_query`. So you could add an `if` clause into `next`, or just use [`update.effective_message`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html?highlight=update.effective_message#telegram.Update.effective_message). BTW, `next` is a built-in name and overriding it is probably considere bad practice …

Comment: Awesome, `update.effective_message` is exactly what I needed! I'll also take care to change the name of my function. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found your error its not update.callback_query you must use update.effective_message

here is your updated code!!!

```
def start(update, context):
    context.user_data["step"] = 0  # Initialize step counter
    update.message.reply_text(
        f"Hello, you're starting at step {context.user_data['step']}.",
        reply_markup=menu_keyboard(),
    )


def next(update, context):
    context.user_data["step"] += 1
    update.message.reply_text("Going forward!")
    update.message.reply_text(
        f"We're now at step {context.user_data['step']}.", reply_markup=menu_keyboard()
    )


def menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("➡️ Next", callback_data="next")]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


def button(update, context):
    query = update.effective_message
    query.answer()
    if query.data == "next":
        next(update, context)


def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("next", next))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Let Me know if your having any other problems in this!!

My telegram id is telegram.me/rohithaditya

Follow me on git - rohith-sreedharan