# How to trigger a command when an inline button is pressed?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to initiate a command when an inline button is pressed.
This is the code:

```
from telegram import (
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update,
    InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
)

from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

token = 'abc'

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

async def start_func(update, context):
    home_btn = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton('home', callback_data='/home'),
            InlineKeyboardButton('profile', callback_data='executive_menu'),
        ]
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(home_btn)

    await update.message.reply_text('start_message', reply_markup=reply_markup)


async def thanks_func(update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text('thanks_message')


async def home_func(update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text('testing home 0')
    await update.message.reply_text('testing home 1')


async def query_func(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    home_func(update, context)
    await query.answer()


def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token(token).build()
    # handlers /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start_func)
    thanks_handler = MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), thanks_func)
    home_handler = CommandHandler('home', home_func)
    query_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(query_func)
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    application.add_handler(thanks_handler)
    application.add_handler(home_handler)
    application.add_handler(query_handler)
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    application.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using `python-telegram-bot == 20.4`. When I run `/start` it gave me home inline button. I want to run the command `/home` by pressing that button. When I type `/home` manually it worked ok. However I want to achieve exact same behavior when i press home inline button.

I tried to await it as can be seen in `query_func` but it didn't work. I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404218/send-a-command-using-inlinekeyboardbutton-python-telegram-bot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `start_func` and `query_func` rely on `update.message` being non-`None`. This is not the case for updates handled by [`CallbackQueryHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html) - see also [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Types-of-Handlers). That's why the answer provided in [Send a command using InlineKeyboardButton python telegram bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404218/send-a-command-using-inlinekeyboardbutton-python-telegram-bot) can not directly work.

I recommend to write a helper function that includes the common logic that you want to execute both on commands and button presses. This helper function should be able to handle the cases where `update.message` is present and where instead `update.callback_query` is present. You can then call this helper function from both `query_func` and `home_func`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks. I want to send multiple messages. With `reply_text`I can do it but when the user presses an inline button, if I catch it in `query_func` I can only edit the message. That is why I need to switch to `CommadHandler` when the user presses inline button. Is it possible? My problem in other words is that: Is there any way to send multiple messages after an inline button is pressed? Currently I can only edit the message.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77006418 for that part